# How can I get user from serializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am trying to override `perform_update` in my `views`, get user from serializer and assign it to `updated_by` in my `Category` model.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, null = True)
    created_by = CurrentUserField()
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, null = True)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default = None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="updated_by")
    deleted_at = models.DateTimeField(null = True)
    deleted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default = None, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='deleted_by')
    
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def soft_delete(self, deleter):
        self.deleted_by = deleter
        self.deleted_at = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

serializer

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = "__all__"
```

views:

```
class CategoryView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == "GET":
            self.permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
        else:
            self.permission_classes = (IsAdminUser, )

        return super(CategoryView, self).get_permissions()

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.updated_by = username
        serializer.save()
    

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        deleter = self.request.user
        self.perform_destroy(instance, deleter)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    def perform_destroy(self, instance, deleter):
        instance.soft_delete(deleter)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is available from request, not serializer. You are already using `self.request.user` in `destroy()` and you can do the same thing in `perform_update()`

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(updated_by=self.request.user)
```

Comment: `"updated_by": null,` I get this after running the code

Comment: Is the user actually authenticated? You can check by adding `print(request.user.is_authenticated)` before `updated_by` assignment. If he's not refer to https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/ for more details.

Comment: OK, I think I see what was wrong, answer updated. Source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save.

Comment: YEEEEEES. Thanks a lot. It works perfectly